# Why vertical alignment is applied to outer text?

Tags: html, css

Whey the `vertical-align: middle` is applied to outer text and not to the text inside `div.code`

```css
.code {
display: inline-flex;
border: 3px solid black;
height: 2.2rem;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
  code
  <div class="code">380805</div>
</div>
```

Comment: read here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: use line-height:2.2rem;

Comment: try this display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

You have to use `align-items:center` to center the content of `.code` class because you are using `display:inline-flex`

if you want to use `verticle-align:middle` , then you have to give `display:table-cell` to `.code` class

```css
.code1 {
display: table-cell;
border: 3px solid black;
height: 2.2rem;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.code {
display: inline-flex;
border: 3px solid black;
height: 2.2rem;
text-align: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  code
  <div class="code">380805</div>
   <div class="code1">380805</div>
</div>
```